# NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: wordpress, api, flutter, dart, app

Tengo un blog que quiero usar como base para una aplicación hecha con flutter. El blog está hecho en Wordpress y estoy tratando de usar la API de Wordpress para que la aplicación refleje el contenido del blog. Pero me arroja el siguiente error:

NoSuchMethodError: The Method"[]" was called on null Receiver: null Tried calling:

Soy nueva en esto, así que agradezco si me pueden ayudar.

mi código es:
`Image.network(data["_embedded"]["wp:featuredmedia"][0]["source_url"])`

Comment: uno de los datos viene nulo, revisa bien que viene en "data"

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Como dicen arriba, uno de los datos viene nulo, personalmente te recomiendo crear custom edpoints para controlar mejor la salida de datos.